# Guardar fichero .csv en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Necesito guardar un fichero `.csv` en MySQL con el siguiente formato:

```
9044;2018/10/05
```

La tabla de la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
id_criptomoneda; precio_dolar; fecha
```

Y ejecuto el siguiente comando con el id relacionado de otra tabla pero no me funciona:

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"LOAD DATA INFILE '../historial/bitcoin/historialBitcoin.csv' INTO TABLE 'criptomoneda' WHERE id_criptomoneda = 1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
```

Comment: No se si entiendo bien, tu fichero tiene 2 datos (entero,fecha), tu tabla tiene 3 datos (entero, flotante, fecha), y quieres cargar tu fichero en esa tabla?, no se va a poder. Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una "columna" intermedia (entre el entero y la fecha) al fichero donde se encuentre un valor compatible con la columna "Precio_dolar" de tu tabla, o bien eliminas la columna Precio_dolar de tu tabla y la vuelves a crear del tipo NULL (o le cambias el indice y el tipo con un alter). Me explico?

Comment: Agrego que el nombre de la tabla no deberia ir en comillas simples, ya que eso se usa para strings y que no hay clausula WHERE en la sentencia LOAD DATA